# Safekill OBS with a batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, obs-studio

I would like to create a batch script that safely closes [OBS Studio](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7qOG07ZHTAhUr3IMKHd8tA0EQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fobsproject.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNGBkR6JQW5D4C-uV28BeoxPXwrfVA&sig2=nA7VuJ3Ufr4fwwG8o-1ZnA) without corrupting a streaming session. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/727724/close-programs-from-the-command-line-windows) thread discusses closing a program with TASKKILL, but when I tried it it didn't work. Their examples referenced Windows XP, is it different for Windws 10? These are the scripts I used following their example:

```
TASKKILL /FI "C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe"
```

and

```
TASKKILL /FI obs64.exe
```

A term I've seen before was called "safe" killing. Can this be done with a batch script, and if so, how?

Comment: What scenario do you have that would require you to kill it using a script? Depending on the recording format, as the options would tell you, it's important to properly stop the recording in order to not corrupt the recording. As per `taskkill /?` you would either need the PID or image name. So your second version should work to kill the task. As you're not using wildcards you could just skip the `/FI` flag.

Comment: I have OBS running on a separate machine, and would like to make ending my streams much easier, it's basically just going to be a shortcut to going to the other machine, and manually closing it there. I don't know what a "wildcard" is (I'm still fairly new to programming).  I also don't mind if the script brings up the save work prompt. I just want a safe remote kills-witch.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with programming. A wildcard is a placeholder. E.g. you could use `ob*` to kill all processes that match, where `*` represents any number of characters. If you want to execute `taskkill` remotely you will have to specify `/S` and possibly `/U` and `/P`. Just run `taskskill /?` and look at the examples. OBS is a rather complex application it might be better to manually stop it. You could just use something like remote desktop to access the other PC.

Comment: Ok, but what does `/FI` do anyways?

Comment: `taskskill /?` what don't you understand about the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would actually just go ahead and read the available help text for `taskkill` by either running `taskkill /?` or looking for the [online documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx), you would see what each switch does and also get a few examples.

To actually see the output of `taskkill /?` you will have to open a command line window beforehand.

Both outputs will show you that, in order to kill a remote process, you will have to run something like `taskkill /s computer /u user /p password /im obs64.exe`. It's up to the program to decide how it handles [`SIGTERM`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll just tinker with this some more to fine-tune it.