# how to close a specific instance of a process using nircmd?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, task-manager, nircmd

I have been using the following command to try closing the notepad file "temp.txt" opened on the windows.

```
nircmd win close title "temp.txt"
```

But this command seems not to work.
If I try the below code:

```
nircmd win close process notepad.exe
```

This will close all the notepad files opened.

So my question is why cant I close an instance of notepad based on the name of notepad windows using the title keyword?
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Some helpful info here: https://superuser.com/questions/727724/close-programs-from-the-command-line-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This command seems not to work

> ```
> nircmd win close title "temp.txt"
> ```

The above doesn't work because `temp.txt` is not the full windows title, which is `temp.txt - Notepad`

You need to use either the full window title, or use `stitle` to match a partial title:

> `title`: Finds the desired window by specifying **the exact title** of
>   the window in [window to find] parameter.
>
> `stitle`: Finds the desired window by specifying **the first few
>   characters of the window** in [window to find] parameter.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source [NirCmd Command Reference - win](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/win.html)

**window** in the description for `stitle` refers to the window title.

The following commands both work:

```
rem use the full window title
nircmd win close title "temp.txt - Notepad"

rem use the first few characters of the window title
nircmd win close stitle "temp.txt"
```